# Timer job and 3rd Party DLL

Tags: deployment, timer-jobs, bin

In SharePoint 2013, is it possible for a timer job to access a third party DLL that has been deployed to the bin folder instead of the GAC?

I have modified the package so that when the wsp is deployed, my third party DLL is copied to the bin folder associated with the Central Admin.  When the timer job runs, it complains that it cannot find the file. I have restarted the SharePoint Timer service, but that did not help.

I can deploy to the GAC if necessary, but my client would prefer that I don't.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Yes, it it working. I finished testing this morning.  I just need to verify that I don't have other copies of the DLL lurking in the GAC.  Thanks for your solution. That saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Ok, great.  Please mark the solution as accepted after you finish your testing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the dll deployed to:  C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN if you want the timerjob to be able to use it.

Comment: Just finished testing.  I removed the DLL from the GAC and stored it in the bin folder as indicated in the solution and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Steve, is it possible that when you deploy the wsp that it can also deploy the third party DLL to that bin folder.  I am able to do that when the bin folder is part of the WebApp, but I don't see how to do it when the bin folder is under the 15 hive.

Comment: Sure, you can right click on the project and say add SharePoint Mapped Folder and then select Bin.  Then anything you put in that folder will be deployed to the bin under the 15 hive (assuming your wsp is set to 15).